# SSH login without recheck all public key

Tags: ssh, authentication, public-key

I have several servers and different users. Also i have two different authorize method: via keys and password.

When i try login ssh recheck all public keys. Is there method to bind public key and server?

Here is verbose :

```
ssh -v root@serv

debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: user1@web3
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: user2@web2
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: root@web1
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: user3@web3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [~/.ssh/config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) file and put per host configuration details in it

```
Host serv1
    hostname serv1.example.com
    user serv1user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/serv1user.key

Host serv2
    hostname serv2.example.com
    user root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rootserv2.key

Host serv3
    user root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rootserv3.key
```

Now you can `ssh serv1` etc and the relevant details will be picked up from the configutation file.